# ToolbarDropdownMenu component missing from @wordpress/scripts package

Tags: block-editor

I've been developing custom blocks using the @wordpress/scripts package and whenever I attempt to import the ToolbarDropdownMenu component from the @wordpress/components package, the component cannot be found. I'm currently using @wordpress/scripts version 17.1.0 ... Is anyone else experiencing this same issue? There are several other "Toolbar" components missing as well (ToolbarGroup, ToolbarItem, etc.)

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it’s what’s happening in this case, but if you’re expecting it because it’s in the docs, then it might not be there because the docs are based on the development branch, so might include components that have not been released yet.

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. I think you're right. I just updated the package to 18.1.0 and the components are now being imported and work as expected in the block editor, which wasn't the case with version 17. Weird side note: VS Code still isn't finding them for some reason, but oh well.